# NAS and Linux filing system

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, nas, file-management

I'm thinking about making a NAS for my home network and hosting it on a Linux machine, but I was thinking: Since Linux has different file naming limitations than Windows, what will happen when I host the NAS on a Linux machine and access it from Windows.

e.g. Linux file system is case sensitive (allows two files with same name to exist in the same directory as long as they have different cases), (also allows some special characters to be entered in a file name that Windows doesn't allow).

My question is: How will Windows handle this ^^^ ?

The whole idea started after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXKkqDZi5jc) video

Comment: Good answer over at the sister site:

http://serverfault.com/questions/70570/does-samba-work-well-with-windows-when-case-sensitive-names-are-enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're talking about NAS via Samba since that is what the tutorial you've pointed to is using.  Note that you probably won't need to worry about this:  Your Windows created files won't defy any of the rules of Windows, and the Linux files that do are still accessible.

Samba has a lot of options for handling this behavior ( https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch08.html#INDEX-92 ), but on my default system I can see experimentally:

- Windows will display the duplicate names and you can open / edit them.  However, Windows won't be able to create new duplicate named files.
- Filenames that are reserved (e.g. con, nul) will show up with odd-looking substitute file names.

You can see an example here (Linux on left, Windows on right): https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxR78.jpg